# How can I permanently change the default sort in Firefox's file picker?

Tags: firefox, nautilus, 22.04, snap

Since upgrading to Ubuntu 22.04, I've noticed that Firefox (version 107.0.1 64-bit, Snap) will default to showing files sorted with most recent first when opening a file picker. This could be by trying to open a file (`Ctrl`+`O`), or when saving/downloading a file.

My preference is to display my files sorted by type, then alphabetically, so my directories appear first, then files below.

I can change the sort by clicking on the column headers in the file picker, but these changes don't last. The next time I open a file picker, it reverts to sorting by recent.

This is not an issue when using Nautilus standalone; if I'm just browsing the files on my computer using Nautilus (not called from Firefox), my sort order is preserved.

How can I change the file picker settings so that Firefox consistently sorts in the order I prefer?